# When conducting a moderation test in a meta-analysis, should you include a category including only 1 study?

Tags: interaction, meta-analysis, metafor

I am conducting a moderation test as part of a meta-analysis and the moderator variable is categorical. One of the levels in the categorical moderator comprises only one study (though there are multiple effect sizes reported from within this study). Can I include this level or should I drop it from the overall categorical variable?

As an extension of this, if I have a categorical moderator with a level that comprises only one cohort (with multiple effect sizes, across multiple papers), would that be an issue?

I am conducting a multi-level meta-analysis with 3 levels of variance (effect size, study/article, and cohort).

Thank you for any advice.